# Java Write incoming opus streams to file

Tags: java, discord, opus, vorbis

I am using [Discord4J](https://github.com/austinv11/Discord4J) to create a bot for discord, I would like the bot to be able to record the incoming voice data to file. I know nothing about writing audio files. What I have at my disposal is a method fired when the bot receives audio data.

```
/**
 * Called every 20ms while audio is being received.
 *
 * @param audio The received audio, encoded according to {@link #getAudioEncodingType()}
 * @param user The user the audio was received from.
 * @param sequence The sequence of the RTP header for the packet.
 *                 See {@link sx.blah.discord.api.internal.OpusPacket.RTPHeader#sequence}.
 * @param timestamp The timestamp of the RTP header for the packet.
 *                  See {@link sx.blah.discord.api.internal.OpusPacket.RTPHeader#timestamp}.
 */
void receive(byte[] audio, IUser user, char sequence, int timestamp);
```

I have a library called [vorbis](https://github.com/Gagravarr/VorbisJava) that has showed up on google searches, but as I stated before I don't know what I'm doing when it comes to audio and I don't know where to start or what exactly to search for. Any assistance would be appreciated.

[EDIT] I should say that I plan to write the data after using the stop recording command.
So I'm asking how I should store this data, merge the different user streams, and write to file.

My Current [CODE](https://gist.github.com/FusionLord/ae3c5cd357dd7872642f659ac7171c68). `updated`